# How to change image captions on a global level

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

How do I overrule already-styled image captions (color, size) on WordPress on a global level?

I have already tried using code like below in my themes custom css editor on the front end but the color for all captions do not change because they were manually made at the time in post editor to be white and now globally I want them all to be black:

```css
body {
  background-color: #CCC;
}
.wp-caption-text {
  font-size: 8px;
  font-style: italic;
  color: #444;
}
```

```html
<p style="text-align: center;">
<span style="font-size:12px;"><strong>Text here.<div id="attachment_1111" style="max-width: 500px" class="wp-caption aligncenter"><img src="http://www.mywebsite/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/image-upload.jpg" alt="Text here" width="500" height="650" class="size-full wp-image-1111 wp-caption aligncenter" srcset="http://www.mywebsite/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/image-upload.jpg 500w, http://www.mywebsite/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/image-upload.jpg 225w, http://www.mywebsite/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/image-upload.jpg 450w" sizes="(max-width: 500px) 100vw, 500px" /><p class="wp-caption-text"><a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank"><span style="color:#FFFFFF;"><span style="font-size:10px;"><em>google</em></span></span></a></p></div></strong></span>
</p>
```

I also tried using this, but it did nothing. My captions remained white.

```
color: #444 !important;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use this, it will let you change the markup of the captions: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/img_caption_shortcode or look for something similar in your theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem here is that you've changed the color of text inside the `.wp-caption-text` but not for **links** inside that `div` (and then the subsequent `span`), which is where your caption text is according to your HTML.

You can achieve that colour change by changing the selector from `.wp-caption-text` to `.wp-caption-text a span` like this:

```css
body {
  background-color: #CCC;
}
.wp-caption-text a span {
  font-size: 8px;
  font-style: italic;
  color: #444;
}
```

```html
<p style="text-align: center;">
 <span style="font-size:12px;">
  <strong>Text here.
   <div id="attachment_1111" style="max-width: 500px" class="wp-caption aligncenter">
    <img src="http://www.mywebsite/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/image-upload.jpg" alt="Text here" width="500" height="650" class="size-full wp-image-1111 wp-caption aligncenter" srcset="http://www.mywebsite/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/image-upload.jpg 500w, http://www.mywebsite/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/image-upload.jpg 225w, http://www.mywebsite/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/image-upload.jpg 450w" sizes="(max-width: 500px) 100vw, 500px" />
    <p class="wp-caption-text">
     <a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">
      <span style="color:#FFFFFF;">
       <span style="font-size:10px;">
        <em>google</em>
       </span>
      </span>
     </a>
    </p>
   </div>
  </strong>
 </span>
</p>
```

Comment: Thanks,
I copied the code to my custom css but it has not changed anything for me unfortunately

Comment: Use more selectors then the class thats overruling your css. The browser or cms will always choose a class thats more defined then the other.

Comment: camputer as mentioned by @ArneBanck, you will need to increase the [specificity](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/) on your selector. The important thing to remember is to target the `a` tag, but you might need to increase the amount of parent selectors leading up to the `a` i.e. `div div div div div div div .wp-caption-text a { /*rules here*/ }`. This is a quick and dirty way to achieve this, but hopefully it helps you understand what I mean with specificity.

Comment: I have now put in the whole code for a single image, not sure if that will help, but it was slightly longer than the first

Comment: @camputer cool - I've edited my answer using your code snippet as an example. The CSS rule has been adjusted to include a `span` after the `a` tag. You'll see it working when you Run the code snippet :)

Comment: Yes! That did the trick! Awesome, thank you very much for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Please use Below code :

```
.wp-caption {
border: 1px solid #B1A79B;
text-align: center;
padding-top: 10px;
margin: 10px;
-moz-border-radius: 3px;
-khtml-border-radius: 3px;
-webkit-border-radius: 3px;
border-radius: 3px;
background-image: url(images/image path here.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center bottom;
}
.wp-caption img {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: 0 none;
}
.wp-caption p.wp-caption-text {
font-size: 1em;
line-height: 17px;
font-weight: bold;
padding: 8px;
margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi,

I only need color and size changed.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your custom stylesheet is loaded last in the source-code. So possibly after plugins' css etc.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" id="some-plugin"  href="http://example.com/plugins/some-plugin.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" id="main-theme-styles"  href="http://example.com/theme/style.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
```

If your stylesheet is called last in the source, this will overwride previously defined css properties automaticly. (If they have the same or weaker specificity).

You can also try to target the **.wp-caption** container elelement and then its children (to increase the specificity) like:

```
.wp-caption .wp-caption-text {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: red; 
}
.wp-caption .wp-caption-text a { /* links inside the caption */
    color: orange; 
}
```